# Why is this font pixelated on font sizes other than 80 and 65?

Tags: css, font-size

http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/6730/4x1f.png

This is an example of the pixelated text when I set the font size to anything other than 80 or 65. Would anybody happen to know why the text gets pixelated like this?
Code to replicate this issue:

```
<div class="top_text">Hello! Please check back some other time, this website is in development.</div>
.top_text{
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-size: 38px;
}
```

Browser: Google Chrome
OS: Windows 8
It looks aliased, I would rather it be antialiased.

Comment: Post HTML and CSS code that reproduce the issue, identify the browser(s) tested, and define “pixelated”. (All text on screen consists of pixels. So what do mean by “pixelated”?)

Comment: It'd also be nice to mention the name and source of the font.

Comment: Sorry, the question should be more detailed now.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome currently uses a really old text-rendering method, GDI, on Windows. [Source](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692). Firefox, IE (and most other applications you run) use ClearType, which has lots of features (like font hinting) which make text look more "anti-aliased".

Chrome devs are supposedly fixing it; if you believe the above link, the fix is due to be released soon. For now, however, most fonts will look badly-aliased in Chrome, except at specific font sizes.